# difference between + and & in ssrs expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I am working on SSRS Report.

I have one question, what is the difference between `+` and `&` in ssrs-expression?

Please share your answer with short example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its depends on how you are going to use them.

**1.) For Concatenation purpose**

According to MSDN:

[image]

- using `&` and `+` for concatenation will result to the same behaviour or output. It will only concatenates two strings.

Example:

```
= 1 & 2
```

*Output:* `12`

```
= "1" + "2"
```

*Output:* `12`

**2.) For Arithmetic purpose**

According to MSDN:
[image]

- using `+` for arithmetic purpose will add the two numbers together

Example:

```
= 1 + 2 //(using two numbers)
```

*Output:* `3`

```
= 1 + "2" //(using a number and a number with quotes)
```

*Output:* `3`

------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Exceptions**

Now there are exceptions that an integer and a string is mixed up or with other types

Example:

```
= 1 + "two"
```

*Output:* `#Error` -> this is because they are incompatible with each other.

- Workaround - use a conversion functions to convert the default data type for a field to the data type needed for calculations or to combine text.

Example:

```
= CSTR(1) + "two"
```

*Output:* `1two`

There are other more [conversion functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255246.aspx) which you can use depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

From SSRS operators description in Visual Studio:

`+` Add two numbers. Also used to concatenate two strings.

Example:

```
=Fields!NumberCarsOwned.Value + 2
/* if NumberCarsOwned=10, result: 10 + 2 = 12 */

=Fields!String1.Value + Fields!String2.Value
/* if String1='curious' and String2 ='guy', result: 'curiousguy' */

="4" + 5
/* result: 9, implicit conversion of the first expression */

="a" + 5
/* error: incorrect input string format */

="a" + CStr(5)
/* result: a5 */

="a" + Str(5)
/* result: a 5, space between 'a' and '5' */
```

`&` Generates a string concatenation of two expressions.

Example:

```
=Fields!FirstName.Value & Fields!LastName.Value
/* if FirstName='curious' and LastName='guy', result: 'curiousguy' */

=4 & 5
/* it's concatenation anyway, result: 45 */

=CInt(4) & CInt(5)
/* even explicit cast to integer it's concatenation anyway, result: 45 */
```

Another useful operator is `And` (logical/bitwise AND), which may help to solve some tasks.

Example:

```
=4 And 5
/* result: 4, since 4 (100 binary) And 5 (101 binary) = 4 (100 binary) */
="4" And "5"
/* result: 4 */
="a" And "b"
/* error: incorrect input string format */
```